# Pytorch model to coreml model for using image classifier

Tags: python, swift, coreml

[model photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP3KM.jpg)

i trained pytorch model, after than i convert it for coremlmodel and it gives me a folder named mlpackage. i can't use it for image classifier, here is the converting code :

```
import torch
import coremltools as ct

model = torch.load('modelft.pth', map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
model.eval()

# Trace the model with random data.
example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, example_input)
out = traced_model(example_input)

model = ct.convert(
    traced_model,
    convert_to="mlprogram",
    inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=example_input.shape)]
 )

model.save("newmodel.mlpackage")
```

i tried to run it on xcode just like this :

output : Thread 1: Fatal error: can't load ML model

```
 func detect(image: CIImage) {
        
        // Load the ML model through its generated class
        
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: newmodel().model) else {
            fatalError("can't load ML model")
        }
      
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, error in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation],
                  
                let topResult = results.first
                   
                else {
                    fatalError("unexpected result type from VNCoreMLRequest")
            }
            
            
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(results)
                    self.navigationItem.title = topResult.identifier
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
                   
                }
            }
         
        
        
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)
        
        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remember to always save file as `.mlmodel` like replace  `model.save("newmodel.mlpackage")` with `model.save("newmodel.momodel")`